# Filtering Pandas Series value_counts on a DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, pandas-groupby

I have a `DatetimeIndex` `Pandas` `DataFrame`. I would like to `filter` the `Pandas Series value_counts` to a by a key `896`.

Here is my approach:

```
df.resample("M").productID.value_counts()[df.resample("M").productID.value_counts() == `"896"`]
```

Unfortunately, this returns an empty data. And yes it is a `string` like this `"896"`

Comment: please provide pd that we can reproduce see more here : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: thank you, the question has been answered :)

Answer (score 2):

Because you want filter by categories, not by counts compare index:

```
s = df.resample("M").productID.value_counts()
s[s.index == "896"]
```

If you are sure there exist `896` value use:

```
s["896"]
```

Or:

```
s.loc["896"]
```

Comment: always to the rescue!